# WMI Provider Host spiking CPU on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cpu, wmi

Background:

- 2010 Dell desktop computer
- Windows 10, [version 1909](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history)
- The computer is sluggish: programs are slow to start, video is constantly buffering, etc.
- Task Manager shows that "WMI Provider Host" is thrashing, taking 50% of CPU.
- Following [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/wmi-provider-host-high-cpu-usage-and-laptop/44cb3953-a883-404a-a94f-ee4f363d3a4b) to use the Event Viewer, there are definitely errors in the event log (related to WMI Provider Host), but they do not indicate the source of the problem.

Question:

What could be causing this? What other trouble-shooting steps can I take?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to fortuitous web searching, I found [this post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-10/wmi-provider-host-excessive-cpu/m-p/1103779) that mentions Garmin Express (an early post mentions Garmin Connect but it is corrected later).

I checked the startup apps on the computer and found Garmin Express running in the system tray. Stopping/disabling that program had an immediate, dramatic impact for the better and appears to be the problem in this case.